# Write executes after read

Tags: input, prolog

I'm making a prolog program to play 'the game of nim', and the program is working fine. I am trying to make a user interface to play the game, where at first, the user has to say he wants the initial state of the game to be. However, when I execute the code shown in the code snippet, the write only gets executed after I type in some input.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
init(List) :-
    write('Enter number of matches in heaps [N1, N2, N3]:'),
    read(List).
```

I want the output to be:

```
?- init(X).
Enter number of matches in heaps [N1, N2, N3]: [1, 3, 5].
X = [1, 3, 5].
```

But I'm getting:

```
?- init(X).
[1, 3, 5].
Enter number of matches in heaps [N1, N2, N3]:
X = [1, 3, 5].
```

Comment: This is likely due to the stream property `buffer` having a value of `line` or `full` instead of `false`, so maybe try changing it before your write call with `set_stream(user_output, buffer(false))`.

Comment: You can verify this by adding an nl between write and read.
write(...),nl,read(...).